# How can I recieve packets on an ESP32 over multicast with EthernetUDP?

Tags: arduino, esp32, multicast, ethernet, packet

I am using an ESP32 and would like to send and receive messages a multicast address. Right now I am using very similar code to the WifiUDP example (https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/udp-examples.html). I am currently using multicast ip address: 239.0.0.0 though I've tried others such as (224.0.0.0).

In order to test the code I'm using PacketSender to send to the multicast address above and do not recieve any messages through the ESP32. [Image to Packet Sender Multicast Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5t8p.png)

However, when I change my address to the device's ip: 10.0.0.21, I see it print in the Serial Monitor that a message has been received. I am unsure what is the issue regarding multicast, and where the error may be in receiving messages.

My code is below:

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Ethernet.init(5);
    Ethernet.begin((uint8_t *)mac, ip);
    Ethernet.setRetransmissionCount(0);
    Ethernet.setRetransmissionTimeout(0);

    Udp.beginMulticast(multicastGroup, port);
    Serial.println("Multicast has began.");
}
```

```
void loop() {

    //Recieve Packets
    int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
    if (packetSize) {
        // receive incoming UDP packets
        Serial.printf("Received %d bytes from %s, port %d\n", packetSize, Udp.remoteIP().toString().c_str(), Udp.remotePort());
        int len = Udp.read(incomingPacket, 255);
        if (len > 0) {
            incomingPacket[len] = 0;
        }
        Serial.printf("UDP packet contents: %s\n", incomingPacket);

        // send back a reply, to the IP address and port we got the packet from
        Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
        Serial.print("Sending message back to IP: ");
        Serial.print(Udp.remoteIP());
        Serial.print(" Port: ");
        Serial.println(Udp.remotePort());
        Udp.write(replyPacket);
        Udp.endPacket();
    }
}
```